# how to know whether a process(app) has been killed?

Tags: android, process, notifications

when a app has caused a exception and been killed ,how can i catch this info to clear some resources associated with this app? are there some servers to service for this situation?

for example, my app will generate some notification,and the app may cause a exception,how 
to clear the notifications when the app be killed?

Comment: ... but when your app is killed the resources will be released because the app is... dead.

Comment: When your app is foce closed/killed, your activity was removed from stack, resources will be released.

Comment: i force kill the app using Eclipse.@kumaand

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about an Exception causing termination of your application, you could make use of the [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) and perform your cleanup.

Take a look at how [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/) makes use of this to send crash reports.